# JFreeChart: Make tooltips last longer

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jfreechart

I have tooltips on my chart which are shown when i hover over the specific part. However it is not shown long enough for my requirements. I was unable to find any methode that would affect the duration that a tooltip is shown.

Any ideas how to make a tooltip last longer?

Comment: See [*ToolTipManager in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11133301/230513).

Answer (score 2):

The ChartPanel class has its own tooltip settings, the methods are not especially well named:

- [setInitialDelay()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setInitialDelay%28int%29)
- [setDismissDelay()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setDismissDelay%28int%29)
- [setReshowDelay()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setReshowDelay%28int%29)

These settings are applied to the global tool tip manager, but only while the mouse pointer is within the bounds of the ChartPanel component.