# JFreeChart show tooltip information on click also

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I am  new to the APIs of JfreeChart and I am trying to get the information of the  chart bars that is viewed on mouseover to be displayed on clicking the bars also. Basically to make the tooltip to display on click also . 
I have added the tooltip like

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(
"Series {0}, Category {1}, Value {2}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

Comment: When you click on a bar, where do you want it to display?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I want to display the co ordinate information

Comment: _Where_ do you want "the coordinate information" to be displayed?

Comment: I information should display on/over the clicked bar

Comment: How long should it stay there? Should it move if you click in a different place on the same bar? What if you click on a different bar? I'm sorry, it's not clear at all what you want to do.

Comment: I just want that the tooltip should not disappear when I click on a bar also

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22781240/230513)?